# using replace method in a loop in python

Tags: python

Consider a text file and 2 lists. In `list_A` there are some letters and in `list_B` some other letters. I want an algorithm to find the letters in the text which exist in `list_A`, and replaces them with letters with the same index from `list_B`. It finds and replaces them, but, each time it replaces it the previous result disappears.

I mean at last, I have the result of the last replacement in the `print`. How can I solve this problem? I mean I want a `print` in which all the letters are replaced, not just the last one.
what could be the problem with this loop:

```
for i in text:
     if i in list_A:
         p=text.replace(i, list_B[list_A.index(i)])
print(p)
```

Comment: Consider [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) + [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

Comment: how about `p+=text.replace...`?

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
p=text.replace(i, list_B[list_A.index(i)])
```

Each time through the loop you're taking `text` and assigning a new version of it to `p`, but you're never updating `text` to contain the new copy (Which you probably shouldn't do, as you're iterating over it).

I'd start by making `p` a copy of `text` outside the loop, and inside, doing `p = p.replace(...`

Bear in mind that with the method you've chosen, you also have to worry about multiple replacements and the order in which you're checking. For example, if you are replacing all `a` with `b`, and also wanting to replace all `b` with `c`, then using your method if you start with `aaaa` you will end up with `cccc` (because it replaces them all with `b`, then checks for `b`...) , when you might have only wanted to replace the `a` if it was in the original string. If you're worried about that, I'd look at [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) as mentioned by bereal in a comment.

Comment: I agree with your comment above about maketrans and translate, but I wanted to make sure the answer would explain the error in the code the OP gave so that it would help with future errors like that. We can do optimisation afterwards :)

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer, so my performance-related comment is irrelevant.

Comment: I generalised your comment to be one about optimisation, it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 temp = text
 for i in temp:
     if i in list_A:
         temp=temp.replace(i, list_B[list_A.index(i)])

print "Original:",text
print "Modified: ",temp
```